# How to display a block if a user does NOT have a selected role?

Tags: blocks, users

I am thinking this has been solved elsewhere, but I haven't found anything.

I am looking for a way to display a block if the current user ***doesn't*** have a role. So, whilst the typical permissions allow a block to be displayed to everyone (by not selecting anyone) or to users with specific roles (by selecting a role), I need the inverse, displaying where the user *doesn't* have a selected role.

DO you have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In global variable `$user` are stored all roles that current user has. So in template.php or template suggestion files you can check if your targeted role is in `$user->roles` and display block if not.

Comment: Thanks Nebojsa. In the end I ran with the details from http://drupal.org/node/51325#comment-124601

Answer (score 1):

in block configure page and in "Page specific visibility settings" section you can enter php code which should return TRUE or FALSE.

global variable $user is still available there.

Answer (score 1):

you can edit it in the "permissions" setting is the "configurations" tab. find that block, and deselect "admin" and "user" and only select "visitor" (or whatever similar option is there, it might not actually say the word visitor)

Answer (score 0):

Below is an answer for users who do NOT have a role with `rid` = 5 (change to whatever `rid` fits for your case).

## Part 1: Rules block visibility

You should be able to get this to work using the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> The Rules block visibility module allows [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) components to be used to control block visibility. This provides Drupal administrators and developers extreme flexibility in controlling when blocks should be displayed on their websites, in addition to the default visibility options provided by Drupal.
>
> The general idea is that if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility, so the possibilities are limitless:
>
> - Need to show a block only for users registered more than a month ago?
> - Perhaps you have a block that must be shown only between 8am-5pm on weekdays?
> - What about displaying or hiding a block based on current weather conditions?
>
> All of this can be done by using Rules block visibility.

With that, and as per the "*if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility*" above, you've reduced your question to making [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) intercept the actual user who's using the site, i.e. if it is **YES** or **NO** (a boolean, right?) a user with `rid = 5`.

## Part 2: Create an appropriate Rules Component

The [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module doesn't have a lot of documentation, except in the [README.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/rules_block_visibility/tree/README.txt#n24) that comes with this module. Here is what the crucial part of it is (to get the idea):

> Configuration is done on a per-block basis. To control a block
>   visibility using a rule component, go to the block settings page,
>   scroll down to the "Rules" tab, and select the Rules component that
>   you want to use.
>
> Notice that to be able to be used by this module, a Rules component
>   *must* be constructed in a very specific way. See the [next section](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/rules_block_visibility/tree/README.txt#n36) for
>   more information.

This module comes with 2 sample Rules Components, that should help to understand the **K**eep**I**t**S**uper**S**imple concept behind it.

By looking at these samples, I was able to create another Rules Component which looks like so:

```
{ "rules_block_visibility_hide_block_for_user_without_some role" : {
    "LABEL" : "Hide block for users without some role",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : {
      "module" : { "label" : "Module", "type" : "text" },
      "delta" : { "label" : "Delta", "type" : "text" },
      "result" : { "label" : "Result", "type" : "boolean", "parameter" : false }
    },
    "IF" : [
      { "NOT user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "5" : "5" } }
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "result" ], "value" : "1" } } ],
    "PROVIDES VARIABLES" : [ "result" ]
  }
}
```

You should be able to import this rule in your own environment.

What this Rules Component does is "only" return a boolean (**1** or **0**), based on the condition if the user has YES or NO a role with `rid` equal to `5`.

With that, we're coming close to an actual answer to your question.

## Part 3:

Head over to the "Block" settings for the block you want to hide for the user without the role with `rid = 5`. At the bottom of it's settings, within the typical "Visibility settings", there is now (after you enabled the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module as in Part 1) an extra tab labeled "*Rules*". Using that tab will allow you to select a "Rules Component" that will do what's documented below that selection list field, ie: "***Show this block only if the selected rule returns a positive value. Important: to be listed here, a block visibility rule must have specific parameters and return values.***".

And guess what, in my case I just selected my Rules Component from Part 2

**Note**: it doesn't matter what type of block it is (created by a view, or something else), it works in all cases.