# How to hide a block or text if user can edit node?

Tags: blocks, users

In a block there's a flag where users can ask for permission to edit the node. The admin gets a mail when the node is flagged. Admin can grant acces with node-acces to a particular user. This part is working.

However, when the user *can* edit the node, this block (or snippet; could use if else statement) should be hidden. I'm looking for (and can't find it) a snippet like

```
if user can edit 
    {'you can edit'} 
else 
    {show flag}
```

How should I do the first part?

Comment: To clarify - do you want to hide the block when the user has node edit access?

Answer (score 1):

Seems it can be done via this PoC

```
if (node_access('edit', $node, $user)) {
  {'you can edit'} 
}
else {
  {show flag}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get this to work using the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module, using a Rules Component that is pretty similar to what I described in my answer to "[How to display a block if a user does NOT have a selected role?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6978/how-to-display-a-block-if-a-user-does-not-have-a-selected-role/204416#204416)".

All you'd have to do is to adapt the Rules condition to make it check if "*admin has granted acces with node-acces*" (as in your question) to the current user.